# Script to swap monitors?

Tags: shell-script, monitors

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 installed and an external VGA monitor connected and I usually turn my laptop screen off and use only the external monitor, but whenever I want to use only the laptop screen I need to go through the tedious routine of clicking preferences>displays>external monitor:off> built-in screen: on, so I thought about writing a simple script to do this for me and create a shortcut from my desktop so I can swap monitors by clicking an executable. How can I write a script to accomplish the following tasks?

1- detect which monitors are on or off;
2- if built-in screen is on, turn it off and turn external monitor on; else, turn external monitor off and built-in screen on;

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#swap from external monitor to laptop screen
xrandr --output LVDS-0 --auto
xrandr --output VGA-0 --off

#swap from laptop screen to external monitor
#xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto
#xrandr --output LVDS-0 --off
```

but the terminal returns me an error:"warning: output LVDS-0 not found; ignoring". Could someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we get the output of `xrandr`? That should tell you the correct display names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to install a front-end for xrandr, e.g. `arandr`, set whatever you want to set there and save the settings as a script (there is an option like this in arandr, I've used it), then use it as a template for your script. This is likely to get all the names and other stuff correct.